# Javascript singleton, how to update this variable?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Quick question. Let's say I have this object:

```
var door = (function(){
    var state = "closed";

    function doSomething(){
      //do something here
      state = "open";
    }

    return {
        activate: function() {
           doSomething();
        },
        doorState: state
    }
})();
```

Now, if I do: `door.activate()` `door.doorState` is "closed". I could do something like this:

```
doorState: function(){state}
```

but that will require me to do `door.doorState()`

I would like to be able to update state of the object and not call a function.

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are just updating the local variable, but it won't update the value of the `doorState` property

You could update the property of the returned object

```js
var door = (function() {

  function doSomething() {
    //do something here
    obj.doorState = "open";
  }

  var obj = {
    activate: function() {
      doSomething();
    },
    doorState: "closed"
  }
  return obj;
})();

snippet.log('before: ' + door.doorState);
door.activate();
snippet.log('after: ' + door.doorState);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Using [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) syntax - [supported in IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Browser_compatibility)

```js
var door = (function() {
  var door = 'closed';

  function doSomething() {
    //do something here
    door = "open";
  }

  return {
    activate: function() {
      doSomething();
    },
    get doorState() {
      return door;
    }
  }
})();

snippet.log('before: ' + door.doorState);
door.activate();
snippet.log('after: ' + door.doorState);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand now.